# can't run rmi registry on my system

Tags: java, rmi

I am learning RMI concepts and had  built a simple program taking reference from **head first java**. All Went fine the first time i ran the code through command prompt.

the next time I ran code  the command:

```
rmiregistry
```

took too long to load and nothing happened.

I even tried the solution in this thread but nothing happend.

[need help to run RMI Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323991/need-help-to-run-rmi-registry)

also when i run my server and client file i get this error:

```
Exception: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.105; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

My Source Code:

**myremote.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface myremote extends Remote
{
    public String sayhello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Server.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements myremote
{
     public Server() throws RemoteException{}

     public String sayhello()
     {
        return("Server says hi");
     }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            myremote S = new Server();
            Naming.rebind("remotehello",S);
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+E);

        }

    }
}
```

**client.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
public class client
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            client c = new client();
            c.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        try
        {
            myremote S=(myremote) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/remotehello");

            System.out.println("Output:"+S.sayhello());
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ E);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'took too long to load'? And 'nothing happened'? As opposed to what?

Answer (score 0):

> Can't run RMI registry on my system

You've provided no evidence of that.

> took too long to load

I don't know what this means. Evidence?

> nothing happened.

Nothing is supposed to happen. The RMI registry doesn't print anything. It just sits there.

Run it and try again. You'll be surprised.

Comment: i did run it several times. But my server and client files generate exceptions mentioned above.

Comment: That can only mean you hadn't started the Registry.